# php preg_replace remove entire line (from a block of many lines ) if it contains an occurence of a word

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Guys ( preg_replace gurus );

I am looking for a preg_replace snippet , that i can use in a php file whereby if a word appears in a particular line, that entire line is deleted/replaced with an empty line

pseudocode:

```
$unwanted_lines=array("word1","word2"."word3");
$new_block_of_lines=preg_replace($unwanted_lines, block_of_lines);
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The expression**

First, let's work out the expression you will need to match the array of words:

```
/(?:word1|word2|word3)/
```

The `(?: ... )` expression creates a group without capturing its contents into a memory location. The words are separated by a pipe symbol, so that it matches either word.

To generate this expression with PHP, you need the following construct:

```
$unwanted_words = array("word1", "word2", "word3");
$unwanted_words_match = '(?:' . join('|', array_map(function($word) {
    return preg_quote($word, '/');
}, $unwanted_words)) . ')';
```

You need `preg_quote()` to generate a valid regular expression from a regular string, unless you're sure that it's valid, e.g. `"abc"` doesn't need to be quoted.

See also: [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote)

**Using an array of lines**

You can split the block of text into an array of lines:

```
$lines = preg_split('/\r?\n/', $block_of_lines);
```

Then, you can use `preg_grep()` to filter out the lines that *don't match* and produce another array:

```
$wanted_lines = preg_grep("/$unwanted_words_match/", $lines, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

See also: [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/preg_grep)

**Using a single `preg_replace()`**

To match a whole line containing an unwanted word inside a block of text with multiple lines, you need to use line anchors, like this:

```
/^.*(?:word1|word2|word3).*$/m
```

Using the `/m` modifier, the anchors `^` and `$` match the start and end of the line respectively. The `.*` on both sides "flush" the expression left and right of the matched word.

One thing to note is that `$` matches *just before* the actual line ending character (either `\r\n` or `\n`). If you perform replacement using the above expression it will not replace the line endings themselves.

You need to match those extra characters by extending the expression like this:

```
/^.*(?:word1|word2|word3).*$(?:\r\n|\n)?/m
```

I've added `(?:\r\n|\n)?` behind the `$` anchor to match the optional line ending. This is the final code to perform the replacement:

```
$replace_match = '/^.*' . $unwanted_words_match . '.*$(?:\r\n|\n)?/m';
$result = preg_replace($replace_match, '', $block_of_lines);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IM1sAh)

Comment: @HamZa The `\n` is always there, sometimes preceded by `\r` :) there might be performance considerations.

Comment: @Jack - couldnt use your code as i could not understand what is the meaning of a partial regular expression  for $words_re

Comment: and also the part of removing the whole line requires an extra trick ... part.

Comment: @MarcoZen I can elaborate my answer if that's what you mean :) give me a while.

Comment: @Jack - That will be great. Thanx. Also is there a way i can use DevZero one liner $newstring = preg_replace("/^.*word1.*$/", "", $string) into some kind of for loop and make it remove the lines as it goes through an array ?

Comment: Fails on the last line. Adding a question mark at the end fixes the problem: `....*$(?:\r\n|\n)?/m`

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression can remove the match from a line

```
$newstring = preg_replace("/^.*word1.*$/", "", $string);
```

Comment: @DevZero, does this remove the entire line if the word appears or just the word from the line ?

Comment: this removes the entire line

Answer (score 1):

As @jack pointed out, let's just use `preg_quote()` && `array_map()`

```
$array = array('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word#4', 'word|4');
$text = 'This is some random data1
This is some word1 random data2
This is some word2 random data3
This is some random data4
This is some word#4 random data5
This is some word|4 random data6
This is some word3 random data7'; // Some data

$array = array_map(function($v){
    return preg_quote($v, '#');
}, $array); // Escape it
$regex = '#^.*('. implode('|', $array) .').*$#m'; // construct our regex
$output = preg_replace($regex, '', $text); // remove lines
echo $output; // output
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/pCha5U)

Comment: Fails for words with `#` in them, such as `"word#4"`.

Comment: Now it does funny stuff when you have `"word|4"` =D

Comment: Hamza - Jack - u guys buddies ? :)

Comment: You should have realized by now that using [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/preg_quote) is the only way out :)

Comment: @Jack in fact, I considered that from the beginning. But it also escaped `|` and I wanted to prevent an `array_map()`.

Comment: You can't escape your destiny ;-)

Comment: Is that a star wars line ? ;)

Comment: netbeans throws up a lot of yellow triangles and a red dot at the first line ... retrying ...

Comment: $unwanted_words = array('div.locshare', 'display:none', '\"', ':\', 'cbc', 'ncip'); netbeans was throwing up  on this line AND when i escaped some characters in the array, i did not get a clean strip.

Comment: @HamZa - thanx for the effort. The problem could be the kind of words that trigger the line deletion - such as display:none , \" , . Its the escaping which is a problem i supose - plus the fact that i dont understand array map ,etc.

Comment: @HamZa - do u think using sed will work easier ? Using shell exec - pass sed the string to process and get a new string ?